# Why can't I cast an object to a float in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm creating an object (let's call it `Decimal`) in PHP that wraps the bcmath functionality and adds some new functionality.

Most of the actual work occurs in static functions like `add(...)` and `divide(...)`.  The only instance methods are accessor methods (hooray for immutability!) and the `__toString()` magic method.

`__toString` works for most cases, but there's the odd instance that I want my type cast into a float/double/real.  I could do this with an instance method or by doing a `(float)(string)` cast, but it seems logical that there should be a similar magic method to do this, like a `__toFloat`.  Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like there is.  I can't find any documentation to that effect.  I tried just doing it as `__toFloat` or `__toDouble`, hoping that it was maybe just an undocumented functionality, to no avail.

I'd even be happy if `floatval()` automatically attempted to cast its argument to a string, but it doesn't.  It throws a `Notice: Object of class Decimal could not be converted to double` error.

Is there a better way or a work around for this?

Comment: Interesting question, but can you outline why an instance method would not be appropriate?

Comment: I'm not saying it's an inappropriate solution. I just think it's odd that there would only be a magic method to handle casting to string and not all basic types. It leads to requiring different interfaces to achieve basically the same effect.

Comment: If you want to overload casts or operators, you'll have to write a PHP extension. This functionality is not provided to userland code.

Comment: @NikiC You're probably right. I've seen the 'operator' extension already. I imagine I'd need to do something similar. Of course, it seems like overkill for what boils down to an aesthetic issue. It just bugs me that PHP includes a magic method for casting to only one basic type. It feels like the API is incomplete.  It should be all or nothing.  But, oh well. *shrug*

Comment: The closest I've come is writing `toFloat()`, or `toInt()` methods.  Sure would be great to have magic methods for all the [primitive types](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.php), though!

Comment: API is correct, you cannot cast to float/int any object, but can cast it to human readable string, it it the same in java

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the `toString()` method returns a string representation of an object to make it suitable for display - think of debugging, error messages, etc.

To return the value of an object you can simply make a `getValue()` method.

Also I'd advice NOT to use static methods. Try this:

```
$numberOne = new Number(5);
$numberTwo = new Number(10);

$numberOne->add($numberTwo);

$sum = $numberOne->getValue();// 15
```